# Pascal 'this' reference

Tags: oop, this, pascal, freepascal

I am starting to explore Pascal with an Object Oriented approach. <strike>I was wondering if there is a `this` or `self` reference to the current object? I have searched around for documentation but I have not come found an answer.</strike>

**Edit**
Through trial and error I found that you can use `self`. Now my question is can I achieve this *(snippet below)* without the compiler throwing a 'duplicate identifier error'?

```
constructor Employee.create(name:String; salary:Real);
begin
  self.name := name;
  self.salary := salary;
end;
```

I have a program below which creates 2 employees and displays their information

```
{$mode objfpc} // directive to be used for defining classes
{$m+}          // directive to be used for using constructor

program EmployeeTest;
type
  Employee = class
  private
    name:String;
    salary:Real;
  public
    constructor create(name:String; salary:Real);
    procedure setName(name:String);
    function getName():String;
    procedure setSalary(salary:Real);
    function getSalary():Real;
    procedure displayEmployee;
end;

var empl1,empl2:Employee;

constructor Employee.create(name:String; salary:Real);
begin
  setName(name);
  setSalary(salary);
end;

procedure Employee.setName(name:String);
begin
  self.name := name;
end;

procedure Employee.setSalary(salary:Real);
begin
  self.salary := salary;
end;

function Employee.getName():String;
begin
  getName := self.name;
end;

function Employee.getSalary():Real;
begin
  getSalary := self.salary;
end;

procedure Employee.displayEmployee;
begin
  writeln('Name: ',getName,', Salary: $',getSalary:0:2);
end;

begin
  empl1 := Employee.create('Bob', 75000);
  empl2 := Employee.create('Joe', 50000);
  empl1.displayEmployee();
  empl2.displayEmployee();
  readln; {pause}
end.
```

Comment: Please post the **exact** error message you're getting, and the line number that's causing it. You have the information right in front of you, and we can't see your screen or read your mind.

Comment: This was the error message, but thanks for your input. I have found my answer.

c:\Pascal\2.6.0\code>fpc Employee.pas
Free Pascal Compiler version 2.6.0 [2011/12/25] for i386
Copyright (c) 1993-2011 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Win32 for i386
Compiling Employee.pas
Employee.pas(11,24) Error: Duplicate identifier "name"
Employee.pas(11,37) Error: Duplicate identifier "salary"
Employee.pas(58) Fatal: There were 2 errors compiling module, stopping
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: C:\Pascal\2.6.0\bin\i386-Win32\ppc386.exe returned an error exitcode

Answer (score 3):

Didn't think that I would be answering my question.

Found the answer [here](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=4785.0).

You must use `{$mode delphi}` instead of `{$mode objfpc}` if you want to duplicate variable names inside nested functions.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use the same name for a parameter and a property. Use the prefix A for a parameter.
2. Don't implement getter and setter methods. Use in Pascal the property keyword.
3. Use the prefix F for private fields.
4. Use the prefix T for a self defined type.

Here is an example for your class:

```
type
  TEmployee = class(TObject)
    private
      FName: String;
      FSalary:Real;
    public
      constructor Create(AName:String; ASalary:Real);
      property Name: String read FName write FName;
      property Salary: Real read FSalary write FSalary;
      procedure DisplayEmployee;
  end;


constructor TEmployee.Create(AName:String; ASalary:Real);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FName := AName;
  FSalary := ASalary;
end;

procedure TEmployee.DisplayEmployee;
begin
  WriteLn('Name: ', FName, ', Salary: $', FSalary:0:2);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I understand that this is the convention for Pascal, but I was trying to simulate Java/Ruby OOP by using accessor/mutators.